# Set dynamic Table Cell height in expand view with Swift 3

Tags: uitableview, tablecell

I'm doing collapse/expand table view in my app. I add table view in my view controller and write code for collapse/expand.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return sections[indexPath.section].collapsed! ? 0 : 44
}
```

When table row collapse, it goes to '0' and expand height will be 44.

 I don't want to set 44 because in each table row, I put 'View' card design with images.  
I would like to be dynamic height according to quantity of view cards. 
Instead of 44, I write **UITableViewAutomaticDimension** but it does not work. 
Please help me how to I achieve?

Comment: What's 'collapsed' state? What kind behaviour it should represent?

Comment: @inokey, when Click on table header, the cell row will expand